# Apply median from a subset to entire column, Python /Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, median, imputation, fillna

first time posting here.
I have a credit risk model data set that has 38K accounts. 25K accounts are training data. The other 13K are OOT (out of time validation). All the 200 columns have the same definitions between training and OOT. Just the data has two parts.

I need to impute missing data. 37 columns of the 200 are qualified for median imputation. Here is my code that works fine. (Due to company confidentiality, I use general variable names)

```
Interval37 =whole[['interval1','interval2'....'interval37']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
Interval37=interval37.fillna(Interval37.median())
```

I must modify this because training is not supposed to see the OOT portion during training, even if it is just calculating median. So I tried the code below

```
Traindata=whole.query('partx==1')  #partx== 1 indicates this is the 25K training accounts
Train37 =Traindata[['interval1', 'interval2'...'interval37']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
trainmedian=Train37.median()
whole=whole(trainmedian)  #Whole is the entire 37K accounts
```

This code runs with no error. Just it is not imputing. Same data in, same data out. I read several posts that apply subset median individually to each subset using groupby. My problem is the opposite. I need to spread median from a subset to the entire data frame. Or I need to apply, transform the entire data using median from the training data. Please help. Jia

Comment: What does this line intend to do `whole=whole(trainmedian)`? Odd if did not raise an error as you are treating a data frame as a function with use of parentheses, `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the *trainmedian* (i.e., Series) to a data frame with same dimensions using the `DataFrame()` constructor on list of series.

```
whole_median = pd.DataFrame([trainmedian for _ in range(whole.shape[0])])
```

---

To demonstrate with random 500-row data and training data sampled at 75% of rows.

```
### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(892020)
whole = pd.DataFrame([np.random.uniform(1, 10, 37) for _ in range(500)],
                     columns = ['interval'+str(i) for i in range(37)])

training_data = whole.sample(frac=0.75)
trainmedian = training_data.median()
trainmedian
# interval1     5.452105
# interval2     5.497201
# interval3     5.516642
# ...
# interval35    5.760942
# interval36    5.319309
# interval37    5.388019
# dtype: float64

whole_median = pd.DataFrame([trainmedian for _ in range(whole.shape[0])])
whole_median
#      interval1  interval2  interval3  ...  interval35  interval36  interval37
# 0     5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 1     5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 2     5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 3     5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 4     5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
#..         ...        ...        ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
# 495   5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 496   5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 497   5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 498   5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
# 499   5.452105   5.497201   5.516642  ...    5.760942    5.319309    5.388019
#
#[500 rows x 37 columns]
```

Comment: Parfait, I tried your line "whole_median = pd.DataFrame([trainmedian for _ in range(whole.shape[0])]) " by replacing whole with my data set that the 37K. It now has 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". I read several posts here about this error. My case is not pd.concate. Any idea?

Comment: Does *trainmedian* result correctly as a Series of 37 values as shown here?

Comment: Your sample code on the 37 variables you created works fine. Strange. In the interest of project time, since I only have 37, I printed out my trainmedian values and use Excel to finish it in 3 minutes by 37 lines. Looks ugly but works. I need to revisit this error afterwards